# Is it ok to take spinlock_irqsave in process context?

Tags: linux-kernel, spinlock

Few questions - Is it ok to take spinlock_irqsave in process context ?? 
Can we do kmalloc or mempool_alloc with gfp_kernel flag inside the spin_lock or spin_lockirqsave in process context .? I think we can not but what problems it can create??
Can we take read_lock and write_lock inside spin_lock or spin_lockirqsave ??

Comment: If you take spinlock and sleep (which is what GFP_KERNEL allows) then if another thread tries to acquire that lock while first thread is sleeping, it will keep spinning which is bad (imagine interrupt handler is the second thread).

Comment: Is it a case of soft lockup ?? Will Sleeping inside spinlock make the context switch happen ?( spinlock will disable preemption)

Comment: I think _irqsave part disables interrupts on local CPU. It doesn't do anything to prevent the thread from sleeping. Also regarding process context, what makes you think holding spinlocks is bad?

Comment: Due to soft lockup issue(getting in heavy load ) and  I am doubting on kmalloc (with gfp_kernel) used inside spin lock

Comment: Yes gfp_kernel inside spinlock can lead to this, so the kmalloc must either be taken out of spinlock or used with GFP_ATOMIC. If the lockup still happens then there might be an additional cause. You can always enable lockdep and get logs via netconsole or serial, to debug more intricate lockups.

Comment: And yes, if you sleep while holding spinlock, then another thread wanting to take that lock will spin uselessly, making that CPU unresponsive. If that happens for a while, then that's a soft lockup.

Comment: Quoting LDD : 
Imagine your driver acquires a spinlock and goes about its business within its critical section. Somewhere in the middle, it loses the processor. Perhaps it has called a function (copy_from_user) that puts the process to sleep. Or, due to kernel preemption, a higher-priority process pushes your code aside. Driver is now holding a lock that it won't release any time in the foreseeable future. If some other thread tries to obtain the same lock, it will, in the best case, wait (spinning in the processor) for a very long time. In the worst case, the system could deadlock entirely.